# Add additional arguments to `BEFORE INSERT` TRIGGER

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, triggers

I have the following issue:

I have a table which looks like this:

| comment | user_id | file_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| text | number (relation) | number (relation) |

Now the problem is: The user doesn't know the `file_id` . This is due to the given architecture (so please do not propose fetching the `file_id`, I know this would be a solution to workaround but it isn't really clean in this case).

**What I want**

I basically want this: `INSERT INTO my_table (user_id, comment, file_path) VALUES (123, 456, 'some/file/path')`

Yes, the column `file_path` does not exist. What I would like to do is (pseudocode):

```
CREATE TRIGGER FOR EACH ROW:
   file_id = SELECT id FROM files WHERE path = NEW.file_path
   REMOVE 'file_path' from NEW;
   return NEW
```

Any good ideas?

Comment: You can't insert into a column which doesn't exist.  Maybe make a view which joins the tables, then use an INSTEAD OF trigger on the view so they can insert into the view.

Comment: 1) That is incorrect synrax for a trigger, see [Create trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html). You need the trigger to point at a function or procedure. 2) Why not add `file_path` column to table? Then the trigger could take that value and create the `NEW.file_id` value . You could then either keep the file_path value or set it to `NULL`.

Comment: Hey @AdrianKlaver . Thanks for the response. The fact that the syntax is incorrect (simplified) should be obvious by having the "(pseudocode)" in there. That's the idea of pseudocode. But yes, I had that same Idea, setting it to NULL could work but also isn't clean

Answer (score 1):

You can do it on Database without triggers.
For example:

```
insert into my_table (user_id, "comment", file_id)
values (123, 456, (select id from files where path = 'some/file/path2'))
```

Triggers works only existing fields. If field does not exist, you cannot use this field inside trigger functions.
If you need using triggers when you must create unnecessary field file_path on your my_table, after then use it. On your trigger function before update or before insert after getting file_id you can set file_path field value to null or you can do nothing. So, you don't need this (file_path) field anyway.

Comment: also a good solution